# Como procurar uma dados de uma coluna em outra coluna no SAS utilizando Proc-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas

Preciso realizar uma query na qual eu tenho que fazer um join entre duas tables. Á coluna que eu deveria usar pra fazer o "On" do Join é o CPF/CNPJ. No entanto, os dados CNPJ da table A está apenas com
12 números, enquanto na table B, está completo, com 14.

Pensei em fazer algo como se fosse o "conter", utilizando o %, mas não posso utilizar no indicativo de colunas, apenas textos.

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE TESR.CAPTACAO_TOTAL AS
SELECT 
A.*,
B.ID_CLI_PRINC,
B.NOM_CLI,
B.NOM_SUB_SGMTO_CLI
FROM
WORK.ESTOQUE_CAPTACAO_TOTAL AS A
LEFT JOIN
MISXRM.LASR_NEW AS B
ON A.CPF_CLIENTE = B.NUM_CPF_CNPJ_CLI;
QUIT;
```

Pensei em fazer algo como se fosse o "conter", utilizando o %, mas não dá certo porque não posso utilizar no indicativo de colunas, apenas textos.

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE TESR.CAPTACAO_TOTAL AS
SELECT 
A.*,
B.ID_CLI_PRINC,
B.NOM_CLI,
B.NOM_SUB_SGMTO_CLI
FROM
WORK.ESTOQUE_CAPTACAO_TOTAL AS A
LEFT JOIN
MISXRM.LASR_NEW AS B
ON %A.CPF_CLIENTE% = B.NUM_CPF_CNPJ_CLI;
QUIT;
```

Answer (score 2):

Se os dígitos que faltam são os 2 da direita, experimente utilizar a função Left para obter somente os 12 dígitos da esquerda:

```
ON A.CPF_CLIENTE = LEFT(B.NUM_CPF_CNPJ_CLI, 12)
```

Espero que ajude